# Find set of elements first or default which sum is closest to a given value then remove form list

Tags: c#, algorithm

After 4 days of reading and researching at Math and CS Libraries in my local area and online reading I am really at a loss and need some clear simple layman's insights to my problem at hand.

Here is my real world problem and then I will show that I understand the problem however don't know how to translate that to a C# MVC 5solution properly.

Problem:
I have built a C# MVC 5 solution to build pallets from an incoming order. I have went through the order and created a list of all items ordered into a full pallet or partial pallet. Then I take the partial pallets list and see what is less than 2800 lbs to see how I can put together a mixed pallet to total up to 2800 lbs. I was doing this very well by splitting the pallet to get to the total for 2800 lbs. However this is great for shipping efficiency, however, this is not customer friendly and shouldn't be split.

From here this is where I am stuck. I was told to take the list of partial pallets and whatever set of pallets get the closest to 2800 lbs put all those together and then the next set(or remainder) goes on to the next pallet up to 2800 again.

I then started to look into what type of algorithm this would fall under and I understand that this is a Subset Sum Problem. I have saw endless stack overflow post that point over to the WiKi page and I have to tell you that I am NO mathematician and can't understand how to get this into a real solution.

here are the known parameters that I have currently.

the Mixed pallet should be 2800 lbs.

the list of items could be on a mixed pallet should be at least 2 items but i think no more 20 items (all depending on weight of item or item type)

here is a list of weights of the current demo
2575, 92, 1200, 640

what is the best combo to get close to 2800lbs? remove them from that list and then what is the next best combo to 2800lbs?

this is my first go at the problem

```
   using System;

   namespace TwoElementsWhoseSumIsClosestToZero
   {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var integerArray = new int[] { 2575, 92, 1200, 640 };
            maxAbsSumPairs(integerArray, 4);

        }

        static void maxAbsSumPairs(int[] arr, int arrsize)
        {
            var sum = int.MaxValue;
            var minSum = int.MaxValue;
            var l = 0;
            var r = arrsize - 1;
            var minl = l;
            var minr = arrsize - 1;

            if (arrsize < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                return;
            }

            Array.Sort(arr, l, r);

            while (l < r)
            {
                sum = arr[l] + arr[r];

                if (Math.Abs(sum) < Math.Abs(minSum))
                {
                    minSum = sum;
                    minl = l;
                    minr = r;
                }
                if (sum < 2800)
                {
                    l++;
                }
                else
                {
                    r--;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" The two elements whose sum is minimum are {0} and {1}", arr[minl], arr[minr]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: are you trying to make this scalable to be able to use more than 4 weights? or will it always be 4 weights?

Comment: I think the best approach would be to sort the array in a descending order based on weight (so [2575, 1200, 640, 92]).  Start with the heaviest then try to add the next one unless it goes over 2800.  If it does, keep moving down the list until you find one that will fit.  If no more in the list fit or you've reached 20 items, then that pallet is done.  And repeat

Comment: Yes I am trying to make this scalable this is just 4 weights but could be up to 20

Comment: I saw that when I made it through the whole problem description.  It's a big one ;)  Does the solution I described make sense?  I can add some sample code if need be.  Let me know

Comment: Yes that does make sense. some code would help on how to do something like that thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the code you posted? I must be missing something because I don't see how it relates to your problem.

Comment: So basically you want to minimize the total number of pallets to pack all the stuff, right? Also: *at least 2 items but i think no more 20 items (all depending on weight of item or item type)*... What are item types? Is this important? And you must be pretty sure about a potential high bound on the nb of items on a pallet, because it is an important constraint for this type of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code related to the explanation in my comment above:

"I think the best approach would be to sort the array in a descending order based on weight (so [2575, 1200, 640, 92]). Start with the heaviest then try to add the next one unless it goes over 2800. If it does, keep moving down the list until you find one that will fit. If no more in the list fit or you've reached 20 items, then that pallet is done. And repeat"

I'm not going to guarantee it's bug free but it seemed to work when I expanded the input array as well.  I'm sure it could be done more efficiently.  Suggestions are welcome.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace palletSorter
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var integerArray = new int[] { 2575, 92, 1200, 640, 290, 730, 50, 23, 500};

        CreateBestPallets(integerArray);

    }

    private static void CreateBestPallets(int[] items)
    {

        var sortedItems = items.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToList();



        while (sortedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var totalWeight = 0;
            var pallet = new List<int>();
            var removedItems = new List<int>();

            foreach (var item in sortedItems)
            {
                if (pallet.Count == 20)
                    break;

                if ((totalWeight + item) < 2800)
                {
                    totalWeight += item;
                    pallet.Add(item);
                    removedItems.Add(item);
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in removedItems)
            {
                sortedItems.Remove(item);
            }

            var printString = "";
            foreach (var item in pallet)
            {
                printString += item + ",";
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Pallet Combination: " + printString + "\tTotal Weight: " + totalWeight);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Here is a sample output (expanded array):

Pallet Combination: 2575,92,50,23, Total Weight: 2740

Pallet Combination: 1200,730,640,   Total Weight: 2570

Pallet Combination: 500,290,    Total Weight: 790

### -

Sample output (original array):

Pallet Combination: 2575,92,    Total Weight: 2667

Pallet Combination: 1200,640,   Total Weight: 1840

Comment: This is a greedy solution, which doesn't always produce the best output. e.g: if the input weights are { 1000, 1000, 1000, 900, 500, 400, 400, 400 } the output ends up being 3 pallets instead of 2. pallet 1 { 1000, 1000, 500 }, pallet 2 { 1000, 900, 400, 400 }, pallet 3 { 400 }, instead of pallet 1 { 1000, 1000, 400, 400 }, pallet 2 { 1000, 900, 500, 400 }

Comment: I remember reading about a greedy algorithm. In the example in your comment "the output ends up being 3 pallets instead of 2" is that because it just goes in order to get to the sum instead of going through the whole possible combinations to get the sum? I like this and have tested this out on many combinations and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Fede, that's a good point, it doesn't always produce the best output as you've shown. I'd be glad to entertain any suggestions on how to to improve the solution.  My fear is that a solution that does a "look ahead" will become increasingly more complex and error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I removed your MVC tag, as this is a general question, not related to MVC. This could have a command line or a WinForm interface, and the problem to solve would be the same.

Having that said, I believe this is related to the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). The sum subset requires a exact match for the sum, meanwhile the knapsack problem may return a not fully loaded knapsack. I would try to make a implementation of the knapsack problem which favors minimizing the items loaded in the knapsack (for candidate solutions that weight the same), so that you don't end up with a pallet full of lots of little items, and then several large and heavy items that cannot be put together.

If you have any issues writing such algorithm, post a comment and I´ll follow up some sample code.

Comment: I agree however that link is the very definition of indecipherable practical application that I was referring to above. I do have MVC solution that this will go into however I was just posting it as a test in a console project to then move that over to the MVC project